# Do function objects belonging to a class receive special treatment upon attribute lookup?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question concerns how a `function` object is transformed to a bound or unbound `instancemethod` upon attribute lookup. Specifically, I'm interested in behavior suggesting that a `function` object, despite being a descriptor, isn't really treated as such. For the following, please assume Python 2.

User-defined function objects in Python implement the descriptor interface. That is, a function object has a `__get__` method:

```
>>> def bar(): return 42
>>> bar.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x104b2eaa0>
```

My understanding is that `method-wrapper` is a cPython-specific type which creates an unbound or bound method object associating `bar` to a class or instance:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> bar.__get__(None, Foo)
<unbound method Foo.bar>
```

Now, writing

```
>>> Foo.bar = bar
```

has the effect of adding the `bar` function object to `Foo.__dict__`. And since `bar` is a descriptor, writing

```
>>> Foo.bar
```

invokes

```
>>> Foo.__dict__["bar"].__get__(None, Foo)
<unbound method Foo.bar>
```

My question, essentially, is whether this last claim is true. Does `Foo.bar` *really* call `Foo.__dict__["bar"].get__(None, Foo)`? The following seems to be evidence to the contrary: We can replace the `__get__` attribute of `bar` with something that is decidedly *not* a `method-wrapper`, and it doesn't change how the function is bound. For example,

```
>>> def bar(): return 42
>>> bar.__get__ = "This won't bind bar to anything"
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> Foo.bar = bar
>>> Foo.bar
<unbound method Foo.bar>
>>> Foo.__dict__["bar"].__get__
"This won't bind bar to anything"
```

So `bar`, despite being a descriptor, doesn't seem to be used like one.

This is my guess as to what actually happens when one writes `Foo.bar`: the interpreter finds `bar`, a function object, in `Foo.__dict__`. Rather than calling `bar.__get__` as it would with any other descriptor, it proceeds with special behavior only invoked by `function` objects: it automatically wraps the `function` in either an unbound or bound method object, depending on what is required.

My questions are these:

- Is my theory on how `function` objects are transformed into method objects upon attribute access accurate?
- How is this implemented, generally-speaking? If it's as I've guessed, are there any other types besides `function` objects which get special treatment?
- Where is any of this documented, if I'd like to read more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does call `__get__`.  However, like all special methods, `__get__` is looked up on the class, not the instance, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes).  In other words, it does not call `Foo.__dict__["bar"].__get__(None, Foo)`; it calls `Foo.__dict__["bar"].__class__.__get__(Foo.__dict__["bar"], None, Foo)`.  So setting `__get__` on the individual function has no effect.

You can see the same behavior not just with functions, but with a plain user-defined descriptor, if you similarly try to set `__get__` on the instance:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print("Getting")
        return 42

desc = Descriptor()

def fakeGet(self, obj, cls):
    print("This will not be called")
    return 88

class Foo(object):
    pass

Foo.bar = desc

>>> Foo.bar
Getting
42
# setting a new __get__ directly on the descriptor instance won't work
>>> desc.__get__ = fakeGet
>>> Foo.bar
Getting
42
```

Comment: *+1* In other words each function is an instance of `types.FunctionType`, so setting `__get__` on individual functions(i.e instances) is not going to make any difference.

Comment: Ah, well that is simple. Your user-defined descriptor proves that this is the case. I'm a bit confused now by the [documentation on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), which says "If binding to a new-style class, `A.x` is transformed into the call: `A.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, A)`.", which suggests that `__get__` is looked up on the function *instance* (which we see isn't the case), not the class. Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @jme: You're right, that is confusing.  I think it's just that throughout the documentation various examples are given that say `instance.__specialmethod__(...)` but actually mean `instance.__class__.__specialmethod__(instance, ...)`.  In the usual case where the instance doesn't define its own method, the effect is the same (because the lookup proceeds to the class when it doesn't find it on the instance), but if the instance does have its own, then these examples can't be read literally, and this is only explained on the doc page I linked to.  I suppose a doc bug could be raised for this.

Comment: @BrenBarn I might do just that and file a suggestion. As you alluded to in your answer, the same document says: "For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary." I suppose that `A.x` counts as an implicit invocation here, though the examples below don't make this clear. They tend to suggest that an implicit invocation is something like `len(x)` in place of `x.__len__()`, or `hash(x)` instead of `x.__hash__()`. In any case, your answer has helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @jme: `A.x` is definitely an implicit invocation, because it doesn't mention `__get__` at all.  `A.x` does the `__get__` call under the hood, so it's implicit.  However, the example you mentioned in your comment, the confusing part is that (`A.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, A)`) *is* explicit, and thus misleading, since as you noted it doesn't actually work that way.